# Check for "handshake" in MPI?

Tags: mpi

Is there a way to check whether a non-blocking receive is posted (for a given source and tag), before initiating a `MPI_Send`? I've got a situation where senders and receivers both don't know who they would like to send to / receive from. My idea was to first post an open `Irecv` on all the chosen receivers. Senders would then check whether a certain rank has posted a receive, and only send if true (continue otherwise). After all sends were successful, receivers would cancel outstanding `Irecv`s.

- This currently works with a collective (on `MPI_COMM_WORLD`) array broadcast; I'm wondering if there is a different way
- I imagine I could do this in reverse, with an `MPI_Isend` and `MPI_Probe`. In this case though I'm worried about what happens to the unreceived send buffers (and have heard that `MPI_Cancel` is bad news for sends)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: MPI does not provide such option. You might want to use MPI RMA instead, also known as one-sided communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform an `MPI_Irecv` with a different tag of the data transfer, using source as `MPI_ANY`. Using a blocking `MPI_Recv` will also do the trick. Once you get the message (`MPI_Test`'s flag==1), you can check who the actual source is by reading `MPI_Status.MPI_SOURCE` (not available if status parameter is `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE`).

If you don't explicitly require that the transfer must be synchronized, then using **one-sided communication** could be much more efficient (the sender just *puts* its data on the receiver.

Additional info: [Introducing One-Sided Communication](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19061-01/hpc.cluster6/819-4134-10/1-sided.html)